# ms access выбрать уникальные комбинации столбцов ФИО и даты рождения

Tags: ms-access

в таблицу заносятся фамилия, имя, отчество и дата рождения. один человек может быть записан несколько раз.

`name1 text  --  name2 text  --  name3 text  --  birthdate datetime`

помогите состаить запрос который выберет каждого человека без повторов

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Выбирайте все столбцы с условием `DISTINCT`. Тем самым вы получите уникальные записи

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
   name1,
   name2,
   name3,
   birthdate
FROM ...
```